# Hiding Visualforce page components based on User permissions using rendered

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to hide components on a VF page based on the current User permissions.
I found that the following worked if the user has Delete and Modify All permissions, but doesn't work if the user only has Delete and not Modify All which causes my class to throw an error about the insufficient access. 
`<apex:column headerValue="Delete" rendered="{!$ObjectType.Birth_Record__c.Deletable}">`
Is there a property like Deletable for Modify All?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Object Schema Details Available Using $ObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_objecttype_schema_objects_reference.htm), View All Data and Modify All Data are not accessible through this variable (if they were, they'd be documented as such).

Edit: I took the liberty of doing a search, and it seems that you basically have to query the Metadata directly (perhaps via the [FinancialForce metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)) if you want to get at this information. There's no easy REST or Tooling API call that gives you this particular value up-front.